# Look up documentation on C types?

Tags: linux, c, documentation

I'm reading over documentation [on concurrency in C](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/CON30-C.+Clean+up+thread-specific+storage) and trying to learn how to do things concurrently.

As I'm reading, I'm coming across types I've never come across before like `tss_t`, etc. Is there an equivalent command like `man` which will bring up documentation on different types in C for Linux?

Comment: Normally, C custom types are either typedefs of standard types (e.g. `pid_t`, `time_t`) or structs or unions. The former are usually pretty obvious from context; the latter should be documented in the man page of one of the functions that takes or returns the type. If you don't see a type documented in a man page you're reading, look in the ones listed under "See also".

Comment: Generally speaking, (not always, of course, but generally,) you should treat these custom types as opaque and only manipulate them using functions provided in the associated header file. Sometimes, of course, you may need to poke around inside them, but it's safer to avoid doing so when you can.

Comment: Looks like your example is from the C11 spec for libc.  Normally functions in the C library do have manual pages but you typically look up the function name rather than the type name (i.e. ```man 2 select``` for struct timeval).  However I've checked the newest version of the "manual-pages" package for Arch and these C11 functions aren't in it!  I'm a bit surprised, but maybe nobody has stepped up to add them yet.

Comment: Aside from libc, it is uncommon for people to write manual pages for the C libraries they write.  Usually you just need to know where your library came from and find out how they publish their documentation. (usually HTML these days)